# installing the latest version of chessx

Tags: software-installation

Why do i get the following error message when i try to install chessx-1.2

```
ted@ted-Satellite-C660D:~/chessx$ sudo qmake
[sudo] password for ted: 
RCC: Error in 'resources.qrc': Cannot find file 'i18n/chessx_de.qm'
RCC: Error in 'resources.qrc': Cannot find file 'i18n/chessx_fr.qm'
RCC: Error in 'resources.qrc': Cannot find file 'i18n/chessx_da.qm'
RCC: Error in 'resources.qrc': Cannot find file 'i18n/chessx_it.qm'
```

The files that can't be found are in fact present in the chessx sub-folder i118n

Can anybody please help

Answer (score 1):

Delete the qm files and rebuiild them with lrelease chessx.pro.
lrelease is part of qt.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Would you mind giving a step-by-step guide on how to delet the right files and how to rebuild them? You'd have a much higher chance to get your answer voted up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here goes what I was about to say:
@William Mills

The easiest way to do what @ReorX is proposing is:

1. Go to the folder above your chessx files and remove the chessx folder (mine was chessx-1.4.6):

   ```
   $ rm -r <chessx-version#>
   ```
2. Re-extract your files (re-unzip'em)
3. Go to the folder you've just created and execute the following commands:

   ```
   $ lrelease chessx.pro
   $ qmake
   ```
4. Continue the compilation as per instructions

This should do the trick.